# How can I pass object in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am developing php API. I am creating  `emi_loan_date` array from string. by doing this

`"emi_date1" => explode(',', $row['emi_loan_date']),`

which is look like this

```
"emi_date1": [
                "23-10-2019",
                "23-11-2019",
                "23-12-2019",
                "23-01-2020",
                "23-02-2020",
                "23-03-2020",
                "23-04-2020",
                "23-05-2020",
                "23-06-2020",
                "23-07-2020",
                "23-08-2020",
                "23-09-2020",
                "23-10-2020"
            ],
```

Now I want to pass other value named `emi_amount` in `emi_date1`.
This would be look like this

```
"emi_date1": [
              {
               date: "23-10-2019",
               emi_amount: 2000
              },
              {
               date: "23-11-2019",
               emi_amount: 2000
              }
            ],
```

I am getting `emi_amount` in `$row['emi_amount']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `foreach` loop should do the trick (this does assume it's the same `$row['emi_amount']` for all entries)...

```
$output = [];
foreach ( explode(',', $row['emi_loan_date']) as $date )    {
    $output[] = ['date' => $date, 'emi_amount' => $row['emi_amount']];
}
print_r($output);
```

One thing I would point out is that storing a comma separated list of items in a SQL column is generally a bad idea.